# Search all mention of the current file's file name

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to add a simple command to search of rails partials files inside my rails app.

I know I can get the filename without the extension with `expand("%:r:r")` but in my case because it's haml I always have double extensions like `app/views/partials/stores/_home.html.haml`, so `:echo expand("%:t:r")` give me `_home.html` and would like `home`.

It seems `split(expand('%:t'), '\.')[0]` is good but now I need to remove the first char.

Do I need to add regex to remove `_`?

After I would like to do something like `:Ag! expand("%:t:r") app/views/` but how to use expand result? For the moment I get `No matches for "expand("_home.html") app/views/"`, expand result is properly "echoed".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `expand` in such case you should use `:exe` command. I'm not familiar with Rails nor Haml (yet), but if it's always `_` in the begining, you can try the following:

```
:exe "Ag! " . substitute(expand("%:t:r:r"), "^_", "", "") . " app/views"
```

And eventually map it to some key binding.

Comment: it's a win. Thanks a lot @grodzik. that's perfect